# How I can find minimum among three value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a notepad file with three line and theses are the value of notepad and each line has three value also :

```
M,2.0,0.6
F,10,0
W,1.0,1.0
```

first we need a for loop based on split by comma , then we need to prompt a number from user then for example in in each line the number should be multiply by i[2] then add to i[1] ,in this case I have written the code but I can not print the minimum number among them for example enter 7 as input each line value is 6.2 and 10.0 and 8.0 respectively ,so we should get 6.2 as minimum that is based on first line of notepad but I will get 8.0 that is in the last line of note pad values .

```
x = open ("sample.txt")
dis = input("Enter distance in Kilometer: ")
def sumof(x,y,z):
    return float(x[1]) + float (dis) * float(y[2]) 

mini = 0

for i in x:
    i = i.rstrip()
    i = i.split(",")
    i = sumof(i,i,i)

    mini = i

    if i < mini:

        mini = i

print (mini)
```

Comment: Here: `mini = i; if i < mini:` the `i < mini` condition is __never__ going to happen because you set `mini = i` right before the `if` statement, so `i` will be exactly equal to `mini`.

Comment: but changing this condition to <= has no effect and still we get 8.0

Comment: Why did you change the condition to `<=`, though? Your code now says: "make `mini` equal to `i`; if `i` is less than or equal to `mini` (which is now __always__ the case), make `mini` equal to `i`". This doesn't make much sense, does it? Anyway, after `i = sumof(i,i,i)`, `i` is a single number, not a list of numbers, so there's nothing to compare it with.

Comment: so in this case when we enter 7 as input then it has 3 value based on 3 lines of notepad then how we can compare those three values and get minimum among them ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a remark: Python already has `min()` to get the lowest value in a list. 
My suggestion:

```
x = open ("sample.txt")
dis = input("Enter distance in Kilometer: ")

def sumOf(x, y):
    return float(x) + float (dis) * float(y) 

a = {}
for i in range(0, 3):
    i = x.readline()
    i = i.strip()
    i = i.split(",")
    a[i[0]] = sumOf(i[1], i[2])

print(min(a) + ": " + str(a[min(a)]))
```

For me this finally works.

Comment: thank you but id doesn't work because the function for sum has three parameters and it shows an error

Comment: yes thank you so much it work for me too, now how we can print i[0] next to min? As you know i[0] is the label of each line in notepad

Comment: We could use a dictionary

Comment: Could you please tell me how ?

Comment: with latest change it doesn't work and says error for must be str not float

Comment: Yeah my fault I forgot to convert the value.

Comment: a is now a dictionary. Do you know about dictionaries?